# set identities discrete mathematics help?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$A-C\subseteq A-(B-C)$

how would you do this question?

and also  b - c(with a line through b-c) $\subseteq C$

Comment: Please define the question more clearly.

Comment: Please check that I interpreted the first problem correctly. I’ll need a better description of the second one, though: I’m not at all sure what you mean by *b - c(with a line through b-c)*.

Comment: Does the exercise ask you to prove these statements, or does it ask you to prove **or disprove** them? I hope that it’s the latter, because the first is not necessarily true.

Comment: it's asking whether it's false or true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the modern notation $A\setminus C$ to $A-C$, so I’ll use it. One way to attack the first problem is to try to prove that the statement is always true. If you succeed, you’ve solved the problem, and if you fail, the attempt is likely to have given you some insight into how to construct a specific example in which the statement is false. I’ll illustrate that approach in detail.

The most straightforward way to show that $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus(B\setminus C)$ is to let $x$ be a completely arbitrary element of $A\setminus C$ and prove that it must therefore be an element of $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$. Suppose, then, that $x\in A\setminus C$. At this point you must turn to the definition of set difference to see just what this tells you about $x$: $x\in A$, and $x\notin C$.

Now back up and look at what you’re trying to prove: you want to show that $x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)$, which means showing that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\setminus C$. You do know that $x\in A$, so it only remains to show that $x\notin B\setminus C$. Now $x\notin B\setminus C$ if and only if $x\notin B$, or $x\in C$ (why?). You know that in fact $x\notin C$, so the only hope of showing that $x\notin B\setminus C$ is to show that $x\notin B$. Unfortunately, the hypothesis that $x\in A\setminus C$ says nothing at all about $B$, so it seems very unlikely that we can prove that $x\notin B$ from the available hypotheses. This suggests that perhaps it isn’t necessarily true that $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus(B\setminus C)$, and that we should try to find an example in which it fails.

Our attempt at a proof suggests that a failure can occur if there’s an $x\in A\setminus C$ that is also in $B$. That’s easy to arrange: let $A=B=\{1\}$ and $C=\varnothing$. Then $$A\setminus C=\{1\}\setminus\varnothing=\{1\}\;,$$ and $$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{1\}\setminus(\{1\}\setminus\varnothing)=\{1\}\setminus\{1\}=\varnothing\;.$$

$\{1\}\nsubseteq\varnothing$, so in this case $A\setminus C\nsubseteq A\setminus(B\setminus C)$.

Comment: I upvoted because you used the modern notation!